# Get smallest item from a std::list that satisfies a certain condition

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming

I am looking for a functional way to solve a list iteration/sorting problem I am having in C++.

Consider a list of elements of the following type:

```
struct SomeElement
{
    /* ... functions and and additional data omitted ... */
    int weight;
}
```

A `std::list<SomeElement>` or event `std::vector<SomeElement>` exists. I would like to query that list to return the element that:

1. Satisfies a given condition, i.e., `MyPredicate(someElement) == true`, and
2. has the smallest value for its `weight` attribute of all objects satisfying the condition.

My list has any number of elements, and zero to all might satisfy the given condition.

I know how to do that in general, e.g., I could sort the list and then pick the first object that satisfies the condition using `std::find_if`, or simply loop over it with a `for` loop, etc. However, I'd like to solve the problem in a functional way.

Is there a way I can use list predicates, generator expressions, and list comprehensions in C++? I'd like to write something along the lines of:

```
myList
    .where((SomeElement const& e) { MyPredicate(e); })
    .min([](SomeElement const& a, SomeElement const& b) { a.weight < b.weight; });
```

Is it possible with C++'s STL, or a Boost library?

Comment: You are talking about list but seems to query the structure as a tree (at least). "consider a list..." vs "all objects belonging to the known parent". Clarify please.

Comment: I think there's a list of SomeElement and SomeElement has a Parent that points to an Object, i.e. "parent" is nothing to do with the list.

Comment: Aside: this the second time today I'm seeing someone proposes to sort a container in order to locate the smallest element. I'm thoroughly baffled.

Comment: I'm trying to see how an appropriately configured `min_element` linear scan does *not* do what you seem to want. Unless the problem is a lie, and finding *just* the minimum element given the preconditions is *not* the actual problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig Agreed.  using [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) with a lambda that checks `parent` before sorting on `weight` should be all that is needed.  Otherwise [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) may be what the OP wants.

Comment: I suggest not using predicates but writing a *regular* loop.  Sometimes forcing things into using predicates or other algorithms is more complex and less readable.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have edited my original question: I do not want to (re-) create a treelike structure, the comparison was just a (bad) example for a more complex predicate in my actual code. I know how to do this with regular loops, but I'd like to solve this problem using predicates in order to learn how to use them. Also, `min_element` returns an interator in [first, last), but my list might also not contain any element satisfying my predicate.